# getting results for a list of primary keys from dynamodb using table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamodB [table](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/Table.html) with which i fetch a single row in the following way:

```
private Table myTable;

myTable = dynamoDB.getTable(tableName);
myTable.getItem(new PrimaryKey(primaryKey, primaryKeyValue));
```

Is there a way for me to retrieve with a list of primary keys? I see that I can use batchGetItem but however for that I will need to use the interface AmazonDynamoDB. Is there an alternative way using the table?

Answer (score 0):

To get all items in your table you need to use [Scan operation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html):

> The Scan operation returns one or more items and item attributes by
>   accessing every item in a table or a secondary index. To have DynamoDB
>   return fewer items, you can provide a FilterExpression operation.
>
> If the total number of scanned items exceeds the maximum data set size
>   limit of 1 MB, the scan stops and results are returned to the user as
>   a LastEvaluatedKey value to continue the scan in a subsequent
>   operation. The results also include the number of items exceeding the
>   limit. A scan can result in no table data meeting the filter criteria.

By default it will return all fields, but you can provide a [projection expression](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ProjectionExpressions.html) to get only some fields (ids in your case):

> To read data from a table, you use operations such as GetItem, Query,
>   or Scan. DynamoDB returns all of the item attributes by default. To
>   get just some, rather than all of the attributes, use a projection
>   expression.
>
> A projection expression is a string that identifies the attributes you
>   want. To retrieve a single attribute, specify its name. For multiple
>   attributes, the names must be comma-separated.

Keep in mind that scans are expensive, since you pay not for items that DynamoDB returns, but for items that DynamoDB reads in the database:

> A Scan operation always scans the entire table or secondary index,
>   then filters out values to provide the desired result, essentially
>   adding the extra step of removing data from the result set. Avoid
>   using a Scan operation on a large table or index with a filter that
>   removes many results, if possible. Also, as a table or index grows,
>   the Scan operation slows. The Scan operation examines every item for
>   the requested values, and can use up the provisioned throughput for a
>   large table or index in a single operation. For faster response times,
>   design your tables and indexes so that your applications can use Query
>   instead of Scan. (For tables, you can also consider using the GetItem
>   and BatchGetItem APIs.).

Answer (score 0):

Reasons for not having batch get item on Table class:-

1. Table class is Thread safe
2. Table class implements the atomic operations of items such as DeleteItemApi, GetItemApi, PutItemApi, QueryApi, ScanApi, UpdateItemApi
3. Batch get item needs to deal with multiple items
4. The most important point is that Batch get item can get items from **multiple tables**

**Example code to get items from multiple tables:-**

The below code get items from `Movies` and `Post` table

```java
DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(dynamoDBClient);

TableKeysAndAttributes movieTableKeyAndAttributes = new TableKeysAndAttributes("Movies").withPrimaryKeys(new PrimaryKey("yearkey",1999 ,"title", "List test title"));
TableKeysAndAttributes postableKeyAndAttributes = new TableKeysAndAttributes("post").withPrimaryKeys(new PrimaryKey("postId", "14"));

BatchGetItemSpec batchGetItemSpec = new BatchGetItemSpec().withTableKeyAndAttributes(movieTableKeyAndAttributes,postableKeyAndAttributes);

BatchGetItemOutcome batchGetItemOutcome = dynamoDB.batchGetItem(batchGetItemSpec);

System.out.println(batchGetItemOutcome.getBatchGetItemResult().getResponses());
```